# Removing an element from an array in a MongoDB document, and another in a parallel array in the same document, without knowing index ahead of time

Tags: mongodb

I have a document format that consists of two parallel arrays, `playerColors` and `players`. Each player object in the `players` array has an associated color integer in the `playerColors` array at the same index. How can I construct a query that removes a player by their `id` and simultaneously removes their associated color integer from the `playerColors` array?

---

My initial thought was to use a find query to locate the index of the player, followed by an update query to remove the corresponding entries in both `playerColors` and `players` arrays by index. However, would this introduce a race condition if there are other potential updates that modify the arrays?

Comment: Would a data model like, `{..., "players": [{"name": "Nick", "color": "gold"}, ..., ], ...}` be more convenient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the data model you are following is not a scalable one. The one suggested in the comments is a better alternative. Having said that, to achieve the update of two arrays in a single query, you can use pipelined form of updates like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchingIndex: {
        "$indexOfArray": [
          "$array2",
          "b"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "array1": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$lt": [
              "$matchingIndex",
              0
            ]
          },
          "then": "$array1",
          "else": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              {
                $slice: [
                  "$array1",
                  "$matchingIndex"
                ]
              },
              {
                $slice: [
                  "$array1",
                  {
                    $add: [
                      1,
                      "$matchingIndex"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $size: "$array1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "array2": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$lt": [
              "$matchingIndex",
              0
            ]
          },
          "then": "$array2",
          "else": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              {
                $slice: [
                  "$array2",
                  "$matchingIndex"
                ]
              },
              {
                $slice: [
                  "$array2",
                  {
                    $add: [
                      1,
                      "$matchingIndex"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $size: "$array2"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "matchingIndex"
  }
])
```

In this query, we first find a matching index, for the element we want to delete from `array2`. After that, we modify `array1` and `array2` as follows: if `matchingIndex` is negative we leave the arrays unchanged, otherwise, we generate a new array by splicing and concatenating them. You can modify the example, as per your use case.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XJoqNkhNl6u)

Comment: It might be instructive to show the `update` if there was an improved data model.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks. What about the original data model is not scalable?

Comment: Besides perhaps the fact that this update query is absolutely massive for what should be a simple thing.

Comment: You can store the `colors` data in the `persons` array itself. In that case, one simple `$filter` will be enough.